# Get the details from batch errors

Tags: apex, batch

I have my batch send me an email once it is complete, using `finish()`

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    AsyncApexJob a = [
        SELECT Id, Status, NumberOfErrors, JobItemsProcessed, TotalJobItems, CreatedBy.Email
        FROM AsyncApexJob
        WHERE Id = :BC.getJobId()
    ];

    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    String[] toAddresses = new String[]{'myemail@test.com'};
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    mail.setSubject('The subject');
    mail.setPlainTextBody('The batch job processed ' + a.TotalJobItems + ' batches with ' + a.NumberOfErrors + ' batch errors.');
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail});
}
```

Pretty standard, and this is what I got in the email

> The batch job processed 18 batches with 5 batch errors.

How do I get the error messages for those 5 errors in the email being sent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the *first* error using the `ExtendedStatus` field of the [ApexCronJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) record. Unfortunately, getting *all* of the errors would require setting a TraceFlag beforehand and then querying the ApexLog files afterwards. This is non-trivial and not recommended. Note that the user who last modified the file will get any error logs by email, so it's not ordinarily necessary to capture all the logs.

> ExtendedStatus: If one or more errors occurred during the batch processing, this contains a short description of the first error. A more detailed description of that error, along with any subsequent errors, is emailed to the last user who modified the batch class. This field is available in API version 19.0 and later.